# How to show that if $T$ is a recursive enumerable theory, then the deductive closure of $T$ is not complete?

Tags: model-theory, incompleteness

The full problem is as follows :

If $T \supseteq {\Gamma}_{N}$ is a recursive theory, then the deductive closure of $T$ is not recursive. Use this and the fact that, if $T$ is a recursive theory such that the deductive closure is complete then $\{ [\phi] : T \vdash \phi \}$ is recursive, to show that if $T \supseteq {\Gamma}_{N}$ is a recursive theory, then the deductive closure of $T$ is incomplete.

Just note that ${\Gamma}_{N}$ is the first-order axiomatization of arithmetic as given usually.

I am really straggling to prove this statement. Any recommendations?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The deductive closure $Ded(T)$ of $T$ is definitely recursively *enumerable* (do you see why?). So suppose it were complete. That means that for every $\varphi$, either $\varphi\in Ded(T)$ or $\neg\varphi\in Ded(T)$.

Since $Ded(T)$ is recursively enumerable, there is a Turing machine $\Phi$ such that $\Phi$ halts on input $[\varphi]$ iff $\varphi\in Ded(T)$ (where $[\cdot]$ denotes the Godel number function). Assuming $Ded(T)$ is complete, do you see how to turn this into a decision procedure for $Ded(T)$?

HINT: Think about what happens if I run $\Phi([\varphi])$ and $\Phi([\neg\varphi])$ in parallel . . .

---

Note: you need to assume, of course, that $T$ is *consistent*. The deductive closure of an inconsistent theory is definitely recursive. :P

Comment: Where exactly does $\Gamma_N \subseteq T$ come into play? (It seems to me that this result holds true without that assumption as an external result. Is that the case? On the other hand, if we want to prove it internally, the assumption totally makes sense to me.)

Comment: @Stefan Everything I've written holds for arbitrary recursively enumerable theories: if $T$ is a r.e. theory and its deductive closure $Ded(T)$ is complete, then $Ded(T)$ is recursive. The assumption $\Gamma_N\subseteq T$ comes into play when we try to deduce a contradiction from this. In general, there's no problem with a complete theory being recursive (e.g. $ACF_0$ or $DLO$), but no complete consistent theory *containing $\Gamma_N$* can be recursive, by Godel.

Comment: Right. We need to model the turing machine in $T$ to derive a contradiction - e.g. by using a fixed point argument or Tarki's undefinability of truth. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this!It was very helpful. Yes, eventually after a while we find a formal proof of \varphi or of its negation from $T$. Is that right?

Comment: @Angela That's exactly it.